# How to setup AG (the silver searcher) in Vim?

Tags: key-bindings, external-command, search, the-silver-searcher

I am using AG to simplifying and improve the search in my Vim. I remapped K to search for the current selected word as follows:

```
if executable('ag')
  set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor
  command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!

  nnoremap K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>
  nnoremap ff :Ag<SPACE>
endif
```

However this doesn't work as expected. When I hit the keyboard K, a small windows opens up in the bottom, showing the following message:

[image]

Then, I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it goes to the results. How can I avoid this window message and go directly to the result page?

Comment: Try adding extra `<CR>` at the end of mapping: `nnoremap K :grep! "\b<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR><CR>` .

Comment: I have it in both. However, adding an extra CR works

Comment: Mapping the mapping 'silent' also works: `nnoremap <silent> K ...`, this will prevent you from seeing the shell output from `ag`. I'm not sure if this is the 'proper' way to fix  this, though.

Comment: See also the [ag.vim](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim) plugin for a much nicer interface.

Answer (score 3):

I use silver searcher too and actually I ended up with this binding:

```
nnoremap K :silent grep! "\b\s?<C-R><C-W>\b"<CR>:cw<CR>:redr!<CR>
```

See at `:redr!` command at the end it cause to redrawing whole screen because sometime after opening results in terminal window, vim doesn't redraw whole screen.

And also there is `\s?` in regular expression. Without it vim would delete first `b` letter of the word.